# Python Beautifulsoup select element

Tags: python

I would like to get links, titles between a date range, but I do not know how to set that 'date' condition in the code, I use:

```
html_link = 'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
TenDaysAgo = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 10))
TenDaysAgo_date =TenDaysAgo.day
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today_date = now.day
date_range = list(range(FourDaysAgo_date,today_date))
page = get_page(month,year)
html = page.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
search = re.compile((r"{}.").format(date_range))
for b in soup.find_all('b', text=search):
     links = b.parent.select_one("b > small")
     titles= #nextdiv/p.text
```

the codes for links and titles are wrong, but no idea how to fix that.
the href is in `<a>` tag, cannot figure out the relation to the date range to access that, need some help, many thanks in advance!

Comment: loop through dates and scrape using https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?Month=04&Year=2021 ???

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code pulls the data elements title and urls based on the date range.

```
import requests
from dateutil import rrule
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def get_date_range(number_of_days):
    date_range_list = []
    date_ranges = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY, count=number_of_days, dtstart=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=number_of_days))))
    for date_item in date_ranges:
        date_string = datetime.strptime(str(date_item), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        date_range_list.append(date_string)
    return date_range_list


html_link = 'https://www.ksei.co.id/publications/new-securities-registration?setLocale=en-US'
html = requests.get(html_link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for ultag in soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'list-nostyle'}):
    for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
        for dates in litag.find_all('small', {'class': 'muted'}):
            clean_date = datetime.strptime(str(dates.text), "%B %d, %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            match = bool([date_string for date_string in get_date_range(10) if date_string == clean_date])
            if match:
                title = litag.find('h2', {'class': 'h4 no-margin'})
                document_link = litag.find('a', href=True)
                print(clean_date)
                print(title.text)
                print(f"https://www.ksei.co.id{document_link['href']}")
                # OUTPUT
                2021-05-11
                KSEI-3629/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127505_ksei_3629_dir_0521_202105140513.pdf
                2021-05-06
                KSEI-3512/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127181_ksei_3512_dir_0521_202105070825.pdf
                2021-05-05
                KSEI-3482/DIR/0521 
                https://www.ksei.co.id/Announcement/Files/127076_ksei_3482_dir_0521_202105051506.pdf
                truncated...
```

Comment: Hey, I think your code works fine! thanks again for your help : ), I think the datetime could be tricky sometimes lol

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, datatime parsing can be tricking.  Doing a timedelta can be very problematic especially when you're scraping.  I would recommend learning how  to use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for converting dates.  I used it all the time. Happy Coding!!

Comment: thanks! I will read the link carefully and hopefully I will be better handling this:), may I ask you a little question? if I want to recompile two key words, should I do with ```re.compile("a" or "b")```? sorry this may not related to this question

Comment: Keywords in a string or a document?

Comment: just some strings like "apples" and "bananas"

Comment: Are these strings in a sentence?

Comment: they are in a link title from a website, and I wanna use re.compile to filter titles contains them

Comment: Without seeing the links, I cannot give you a solid answer.   Test your regex here https://regexr.com.  There is likely an answer to this problem under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex  LMK if you get stuck.